# Autofocus attribute in TextAngular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap, textangular

Need help with TextAngular. I want to auto-focus when the page loads but can't seem to get it working. Here's my code:

```
    <div text-angular ng-model="formData.solutionText"></div>
```

I tried adding this too but it doesn't seem to work. I tried with ngfocus too but i'm going wrong somewhere and it's not working!

```
    ta-focussed-class="focussed"
```

Could anyone point me to the right direction on how to get this going?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like text-angular directive doesn't come up with a support for autofocus, you could probably try this:

```
<text-angular ng-model="formData.solutionText">
  <textarea name="Text1" cols="20" rows="10" class="form-control" autofocus></textarea>
</text-angular>
```

See this Link: http://plnkr.co/edit/ML3rLNutIz1XMo3oO2UC?p=preview

Comment: Yeah it doesn't and this solution isn't working :( but thank you so much.

Comment: added a plunker link .check it out.